# Ionic 2 : Translate doesn't work after android build, but same code works in browser

Tags: ionic2

I am trying to develop an application which will support multi language. The basic flow of application will be to read the locale by Cordova Globalization i.e '@ionic-native/globalization' and set the language locale to TranslateService from '@ngx-translate/core' for text translations.

Please refer to below code and guide me to make the translation to work even after android run. It was ironic that with the same code translation is working fine in browser :(

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Nav, Platform, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { Globalization } from '@ionic-native/globalization';

import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;
  rootPage:any = LoginPage;
  userName: any;

  constructor(
    platform: Platform, 
    statusBar: StatusBar, 
    public alertCtrl: AlertController,
    splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private translateService: TranslateService,
    private globalization: Globalization) {

    this.translateService.setDefaultLang('en');
    this.translateService.use('en');

    //this.translateService.setDefaultLang('fr');
    //this.translateService.use('fr');

    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();

      this.globalization.getPreferredLanguage()
      .then(result => {
      // To check and convert language locale
      let languageCode = this.getSuitableLanguage(result.value);

      this.translateService.setDefaultLang(languageCode);
      this.translateService.use(languageCode);
    })
    .catch(e => {
      let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'Error',
        subTitle: e,
        buttons: ['OK']
      });
      alert.present();
    });
});
    });
  }

  getSuitableLanguage(languageCode) {
    let langCode = languageCode.substring(0, 2).toLowerCase();

    switch(langCode){
      case 'en' : {
        return 'en';
      }
      case 'fr' : {
        return 'fr';
      }
      default : {
        return 'en';
      }
    }
  }

}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { Globalization } from '@ionic-n5 ative/globalization';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    LoginPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
          provide: TranslateLoader,
          useFactory: (HttpLoaderFactory),
          deps: [HttpClient]
      }
  })
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    LoginPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    HTTP,
    Globalization,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}

export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}
```

**login.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="light">
    <ion-title>
        LOGIN
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding class="noContentScrollbar" scroll="false" scrollbar-x="false" scrollbar-y="false">
  <div class="spacer" style="height:100px;" id="login-spacer2"></div>

  <ion-list inset>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-input 
        id="idUserName" 
        type="text" 
        placeholder="{{'Login.user' | translate }}" 
        [(ngModel)]="usercreds.name"></ion-input>
      <ion-icon name="person" item-right></ion-icon>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-input 
        id="idPassword" 
        type="password" 
        placeholder="{{'Login.password' | translate }}" 
        [(ngModel)]="usercreds.password"></ion-input>
      <ion-icon name="key" item-right></ion-icon>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

  <div padding>
    <button ion-button color="primary" block>
      {{'Login.btn_loginCaps' | translate }}
    </button>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

**en.json**

```
{
    "Login" : {
        "user" : "User",
        "password" : "Password",
        "btn_loginCaps" : "LOGIN"
    }
}
```

**fr.json**

```
{
    "Login" : {
        "user" : "*User",
        "password" : "*Password",
        "btn_loginCaps" : "*LOGIN"
    }
}
```

> I am working on french translation, but for the time i just put *
>   before the text.

**Result looks in mobile** after app run

[image]

**Result looks in Ionic lab (browser)** with same code (no change)

[image]

Help me to correct my code to make the translation to run even after android build/run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long R&D finally i found one mistake in my code. In **app.module.ts** look for the function

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}
```

Replace below code with the code in above function

```
return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
```

That's it. Hopefully this example will help you to resolve you issue too.